# Find Second Level Children In Django Mptt

Tags: javascript, django, django-mptt

I have a model that have a field like this:

> parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True,
>   related_name='children')

I want to add parent to a select box and then with onclick, select the second level children.

```
parent1
-section1
--child1

parent2
-section2
--child2
```

I have tried all things. (level__gt), (level__lt) ....I have read the django-mptt document. How can I fetch second child? I dont want use ul and li. I want to add all parents in a select and then fetch second children with clik to parents.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

not sure to fully understand your question. Here some shortcuts:

```
# all 2^ level 
Model.objects.filter(level=1)

# all leafs (any level)
Model.objects.filter(lft=F('rght') - 1)

# the whole tree except the first node
Model.objects.filter(tree_id=1)[1:]

# all the nodes with childs
Model.objects.exclude(tree_id=1)

# all childs of a node
node.get_children()

# the whole tree of a node (from the top to the last child)
Model.objects.filter(tree_id=node.tree_id)
```